# Groups are empty while authenticating using DEX (LDAP)

Tags: kubernetes, ldap, ldap-query, openid-connect, openid-dex

I have been trying to authenticate OIDC using DEX for LDAP. I have succeeded in authenticating but the problem is, LDAP search is not returning the groups. Following are my DEX configs and LDAP Data. Please help me out

Screenshot: Login successful, groups are empty

[image]

**My Dex Config**

```
# User search maps a username and password entered by a user to a LDAP entry.
userSearch:
# BaseDN to start the search from. It will translate to the query
# "(&(objectClass=person)(uid=<username>))".
baseDN: ou=People,dc=ec2-54-185-211-121,dc=us-west-2,dc=compute,dc=amazonaws,dc=com
# Optional filter to apply when searching the directory.
#filter: "(objectClass=posixAccount)"
# username attribute used for comparing user entries. This will be translated
# and combine with the other filter as "(<attr>=<username>)".
username: mail
# The following three fields are direct mappings of attributes on the user entry.
# String representation of the user.
idAttr: uid
# Required. Attribute to map to Email.
emailAttr: mail
# Maps to display name of users. No default value.
nameAttr: uid

# Group search queries for groups given a user entry.
groupSearch:
# BaseDN to start the search from. It will translate to the query
# "(&(objectClass=group)(member=<user uid>))".
baseDN: dc=ec2-54-185-211-121,dc=us-west-2,dc=compute,dc=amazonaws,dc=com
# Optional filter to apply when searching the directory.
#filter: "(objectClass=posixGroup)"
# Following two fields are used to match a user to a group. It adds an additional
# requirement to the filter that an attribute in the group must match the user's
# attribute value.
userAttr: uid
groupAttr: memberUid
# Represents group name.
nameAttr: cn
```

**My LDAP Data**

> dn:
>   ou=People,dc=ec2-54-185-211-121,dc=us-west-2,dc=compute,dc=amazonaws,dc=com
>   ou: People objectClass: organizationalUnit
>
> dn:
>   uid=johndoe,ou=People,dc=ec2-54-185-211-121,dc=us-west-2,dc=compute,dc=amazonaws,dc=com
>   gecos: John Doe uid: johndoe loginShell: / bin / bash mail:
>   john.doe@example.org homeDirectory: / home / jdoe cn: John Doe sn: Doe
>   uidNumber: 10002 objectClass: posixAccount objectClass: inetOrgPerson
>   objectClass: top userPassword: bar gidNumber: 10002
>
> dn:
>   uid=janedoe,ou=People,dc=ec2-54-185-211-121,dc=us-west-2,dc=compute,dc=amazonaws,dc=com
>   gecos: Jane Doe uid: janedoe loginShell: / bin / bash mail:
>   jane.doe@example.org homeDirectory: / home / jdoe cn: Jane Doe sn: Doe
>   uidNumber: 10001 objectClass: posixAccount objectClass: inetOrgPerson
>   objectClass: top userPassword: foo gidNumber: 10001
>
> dn:
>   ou=Groups,dc=ec2-54-185-211-121,dc=us-west-2,dc=compute,dc=amazonaws,dc=com
>   ou: Groups objectClass: organizationalUnit
>
> dn:
>   cn=admins,ou=Groups,dc=ec2-54-185-211-121,dc=us-west-2,dc=compute,dc=amazonaws,dc=com
>   cn: admins objectClass: posixGroup objectClass: top gidNumber: 20001
>   memberUid: janedoe memberUid: johndoe
>
> dn:
>   cn=developers,ou=Groups,dc=ec2-54-185-211-121,dc=us-west-2,dc=compute,dc=amazonaws,dc=com
>   cn: developers objectClass: posixGroup objectClass: top gidNumber:
>   20002 memberUid: janedoe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for a late replay but I didnt know the answer until now :)

I had the same problem, in my setup I used `dex (quay.io/dexidp/dex:v2.16.0)` to use MS AD. I used **kubernetes 1.13** in my tests.

To generate kubeconfig i used `heptiolabs/gangway (gcr.io/heptio-images/gangway:v3.0.0)` and for handle dashboard login i used `pusher/oauth2_proxy (quay.io/pusher/oauth2_proxy)`.

I spent a lot of time trying different ldap setups in dex but didnt get the AD groups to show up in dex log or get them to work in kubernetes, and every example I read was using only users.

The problem and solution for me was not in the dex config, dex will request groups from ldap if you tell dex to do so.
Its all in the clients. OIDC have a "concept" of scopes and I guess that most (all?) oidc clients implement it, at least both gangway and oauth2-proxy does.
So the solution for me was to configure the client (gangway and oauth2-proxy in my case) so that they also ask dex for groups.

In gangway I used the following config (including the comments)

```
# Used to specify the scope of the requested Oauth authorization.
# scopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access"]
scopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access", "groups"]
```

For oauth2-proxy I added this to the args deployment

```
- args:
        - --scope=openid profile email groups
```

And then I could use groups instead of users in my rolebindings, dont forget to also configure the api-server to use dex for its oidc.

Hope that helps

-Robert

Comment: Did you encounter the situation if the group is empty and we are still allowed to login? With the above step, I get the group information, but if group is empty, I shouldnt be allowed to login correct?  I have explained my situation here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58276195/mandate-group-search-condition-in-dex-ldap-coonector

Comment: yes, you are allowed to login, for example we use dashboard and oauth2-proxy per cluster and everyone with a valid account i AD can login to the dashboard. But if you dont have any rights (roles) for that cluster you dont see anything.